# Maximo Selenium : can't load any page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, maximo

i need to do test automation on an IBM Maximo projet.

I found that online : https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=4d90a532-31a3-41bd-a128-2186fdae50b8
And i try to use it.

When i run the class "TpaeTestDriver" with TestNG, all start :

- The program launch google chrome but juste stop a few minutes after it close.

This is the log and i don't know what to do :

Thanks everyone who spend time on it :)

> [RemoteTestNG] revisions:     git.commit.id=f7160ab
>     git.branch=f7160ab041ae763e01e10b6867b5d40d49e2688e
>     git.build.version=1.3.1 [RemoteTestNG] loaded class
>   org.testng.internal.Version at
>   file:/D:/Profiles/valegoupil/Desktop/TEST%20AUTO/Maximo%20Selenium%20Automation/Automation/lib/testng-6.8.jar
>   [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.8.0 [RemoteTestNG] Invoked
>   with -serport 57315 -protocol json -d
>   D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo Selenium
>   Automation\Automation\test-output
>   d:\Profiles\valegoupil\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1094889935\testng-customsuite.xml
>   [BaseMessageSender] Waiting for Eclipse client on localhost:57315
>   [BaseMessageSender] Received a connection from Eclipse on
>   localhost:57315 [BaseMessageSender] Connection established, starting
>   reader thread [BaseMessageSender] ReaderThread waiting for an admin
>   message
>
> [JsonMessageSender] Sending message [GenericMessage ==> suiteCount:1,
>   testCount:1] [BaseMessageSender] ReaderThread received admin
>   message:>ACK [BaseMessageSender] Admin message:>ACK
>   [BaseMessageSender] Received ACK:>ACK [BaseMessageSender] Admin
>   message:>ACK [BaseMessageSender] Received ACK:>ACK [TestRunner]
>   Running the tests in 'Default test' with parallel mode:false [RunInfo]
>   Adding method selector: org.testng.internal.XmlMethodSelector@5a955565
>   priority: 10 [TestClass] Creating TestClass for [ClassImpl
>   class=tests.testdriver.TpaeTestDriver] [TestClass] Adding method
>   TestDriver.Driver()[pri:0, instance:null] on TestClass class
>   tests.testdriver.TpaeTestDriver [XmlMethodSelector] Including method
>   tests.testdriver.Driver() [TestNG] Running:
>   D:\Profiles\valegoupil\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1094889935\testng-customsuite.xml
>
> [JsonMessageSender] Sending message [SuiteMessage ==> suite:Default
>   suite, starting, methodCount:0] [BaseMessageSender] Admin message:>ACK
>   [BaseMessageSender] Received ACK:>ACK [BaseMessageSender] Admin
>   message:>ACK [BaseMessageSender] Received ACK:>ACK [Invoker
>   1321530272] Keeping method
>   AutomationBaseTest.beforeSuite(org.testng.ITestContext)[pri:0,
>   instance:tests.testdriver.TpaeTestDriver@3835c46] for class null
>   [Invoker 1321530272] Invoking @BeforeSuite
>   AutomationBaseTest.beforeSuite(org.testng.ITestContext)[pri:0,
>   instance:tests.testdriver.TpaeTestDriver@3835c46] 14:15:46.134 INFO -
>   Java: Oracle Corporation 25.131-b11 14:15:46.135 INFO - OS: Windows 10
>   10.0 amd64 14:15:46.137 INFO - vnull [null], with Core vnull [null] 14:15:46.273 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to:
>   http://127.0.0.1:58443/wd/hub 14:15:46.276 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
>   14:15:46.281 INFO - Started
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server] 14:15:46.283 INFO -
>   Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@741a8937
>   14:15:46.284 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd] 14:15:46.284 INFO -
>   Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
>   14:15:46.284 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/] 14:15:46.287 INFO -
>   Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:58443 14:15:46.287 INFO - Started
>   org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@6c40365c [SuiteRunner] Created 1
>   TestRunners [TestRunner] Running test Default test on 1  classes, 
>   included groups:[] excluded groups:[]
>   ===== Test class tests.testdriver.TpaeTestDriver   @BeforeClass AutomationBaseTest.beforeClass(org.testng.ITestContext)[pri:0,
>   instance:tests.testdriver.TpaeTestDriver@3835c46]
>       @Test TestDriver.Driver()[pri:0, instance:tests.testdriver.TpaeTestDriver@3835c46]   @AfterClass
>   AutomationBaseTest.afterClass()[pri:0,
>   instance:tests.testdriver.TpaeTestDriver@3835c46]
>   ====== [JsonMessageSender] Sending message [TestMessage ==> suite:Default suite, testName:Default test, passed:0, failed:0]
>   [BaseMessageSender] Admin message:>ACK [BaseMessageSender] Received
>   ACK:>ACK [BaseMessageSender] Admin message:>ACK [BaseMessageSender]
>   Received ACK:>ACK [Invoker 1321530272] Keeping method
>   AutomationBaseTest.beforeClass(org.testng.ITestContext)[pri:0,
>   instance:tests.testdriver.TpaeTestDriver@3835c46] for class [TestClass
>   name=class tests.testdriver.TpaeTestDriver] [Invoker 1321530272]
>   Invoking @BeforeClass
>   AutomationBaseTest.beforeClass(org.testng.ITestContext)[pri:0,
>   instance:tests.testdriver.TpaeTestDriver@3835c46] 14:15:48.573 INFO -
>   Executing: [new session: {chrome.binary=C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google..., browserName=chrome,
>   chromeOptions={args=[--disable-popup-blocki..., version=,
>   platform=ANY}] at URL: /session) Starting ChromeDriver 2.35.528161
>   (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73) on port 57082 Only local
>   connections are allowed. 14:15:51.199 INFO - Done: /session
>   14:15:51.205 INFO - Executing:
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.GetSessionCapabilities@17276ab0
>   at URL: /session/1520255746238) 14:15:51.206 INFO - Done:
>   /session/1520255746238 14:15:51.298 INFO - Executing: [implicitly
>   wait: 0] at URL: /session/1520255746238/timeouts/implicit_wait)
>   14:15:51.303 INFO - Done:
>   /session/1520255746238/timeouts/implicit_wait 14:15:51.308 INFO -
>   Executing: [implicitly wait: 0] at URL:
>   /session/1520255746238/timeouts/implicit_wait) 14:15:51.311 INFO -
>   Done: /session/1520255746238/timeouts/implicit_wait 14:15:51.316 INFO
>   - Executing: [implicitly wait: 10000] at URL: /session/1520255746238/timeouts/implicit_wait) 14:15:51.319 INFO -
>   Done: /session/1520255746238/timeouts/implicit_wait 14:15:51.323 INFO
>   - Executing: [delete all cookies] at URL: /session/1520255746238/cookie) 14:15:51.345 INFO - Done:
>   /session/1520255746238/cookie 14:15:51.350 INFO - Executing: [get
>   current window handle] at URL: /session/1520255746238/window_handle)
>   14:15:51.353 INFO - Done: /session/1520255746238/window_handle
>   [JsonMessageSender] Sending message [TestResultMessage ==>
>   suite:Default suite, test:Default test,
>   class:tests.testdriver.TpaeTestDriver, method:Driver, parameters:]
>   [Invoker 1321530272] Invoking tests.testdriver.TestDriver.Driver
>   [BaseMessageSender] Admin message:>ACK [BaseMessageSender] Received
>   ACK:>ACK [BaseMessageSender] Admin message:>ACK [BaseMessageSender]
>   Received ACK:>ACK 14:15:51.381 INFO - Executing: [get current window
>   handle] at URL: /session/1520255746238/window_handle) 14:15:51.385
>   INFO - Done: /session/1520255746238/window_handle 14:15:51.397 INFO -
>   Executing: [execute script: return navigator.userAgent, []] at URL:
>   /session/1520255746238/execute) 14:15:51.406 INFO - Done:
>   /session/1520255746238/execute 14:15:51.413 INFO - Executing: [execute
>   script: return navigator.userAgent, []] at URL:
>   /session/1520255746238/execute) 14:15:51.419 INFO - Done:
>   /session/1520255746238/execute 14:15:51.425 INFO - Executing: [execute
>   script: return navigator.userAgent, []] at URL:
>   /session/1520255746238/execute) 14:15:51.431 INFO - Done:
>   /session/1520255746238/execute 14:15:51.438 INFO - Executing: [get
>   current window handle] at URL: /session/1520255746238/window_handle)
>   14:15:51.442 INFO - Done: /session/1520255746238/window_handle
>   [JsonMessageSender] Sending message [TestResultMessage ==>
>   suite:Default suite, test:Default test,
>   class:tests.testdriver.TpaeTestDriver, method:Driver, parameters:]
>   [Invoker 1321530272] Keeping method
>   AutomationBaseTest.afterClass()[pri:0,
>   instance:tests.testdriver.TpaeTestDriver@3835c46] for class [TestClass
>   name=class tests.testdriver.TpaeTestDriver] [BaseMessageSender] Admin
>   message:>ACK [BaseMessageSender] Received ACK:>ACK [BaseMessageSender]
>   Admin message:>ACK [BaseMessageSender] Received ACK:>ACK [Invoker
>   1321530272] Invoking @AfterClass
>   AutomationBaseTest.afterClass()[pri:0,
>   instance:tests.testdriver.TpaeTestDriver@3835c46] 14:17:14.363 INFO -
>   Executing: [close window] at URL: /session/1520255746238/window)
>   14:17:16.675 INFO - Done: /session/1520255746238/window 14:17:16.688
>   INFO - Executing: [delete session: 1520255746238] at URL:
>   /session/1520255746238) 14:17:17.799 INFO - Done:
>   /session/1520255746238
>   ===== Invoked methods   AutomationBaseTest.beforeClass(org.testng.ITestContext)[pri:0,
>   instance:tests.testdriver.TpaeTestDriver@3835c46]org.testng.TestRunner@ed3068a
>   58940486
>       TestDriver.Driver()[pri:0, instance:tests.testdriver.TpaeTestDriver@3835c46] 58940486
>   AutomationBaseTest.afterClass()[pri:0,
>   instance:tests.testdriver.TpaeTestDriver@3835c46] 58940486
>   ===== Creating D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo Selenium Automation\Automation\test-output\Default suite\Default
>   test.html Creating D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo
>   Selenium Automation\Automation\test-output\Default suite\Default
>   test.xml [JsonMessageSender] Sending message [TestMessage ==>
>   suite:Default suite, testName:Default test, passed:0, failed:1]
>   [BaseMessageSender] Admin message:>ACK [BaseMessageSender] Received
>   ACK:>ACK [BaseMessageSender] Admin message:>ACK [BaseMessageSender]
>   Received ACK:>ACK FAILED: Driver
>   org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException:  Command duration or
>   timeout: 4 milliseconds Build info: version: '2.20.0', revision:
>   '16008', time: '2012-02-27 19:03:59' System info: os.name: 'Windows
>   10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
>   Driver info: driver.version: TestDriver   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:170)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:123)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:438)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$64390f20.CGLIB$execute$3()
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$64390f20$$FastClassByCGLIB$$b5faa7ea.invoke()
>     at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:215)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.Augmenter$CompoundHandler.intercept(Augmenter.java:262)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$64390f20.execute()
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteWindow.getSize(RemoteWebDriver.java:614)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWindow.getSize(EventFiringWebDriver.java:610)
>     at tests.testdriver.TestDriver.Driver(TestDriver.java:284)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
>
> ===============================================
>       Default test
>
> ## Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
>
> [Invoker 1321530272] Keeping method
>   AutomationBaseTest.afterSuite()[pri:0,
>   instance:tests.testdriver.TpaeTestDriver@3835c46] for class null
>   [Invoker 1321530272] Invoking @AfterSuite
>   AutomationBaseTest.afterSuite()[pri:0,
>   instance:tests.testdriver.TpaeTestDriver@3835c46] 14:17:17.859 INFO -
>   Stopping Acceptor ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=58443]
>   14:17:17.960 INFO - Stopped SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:58443
>   14:17:18.012 INFO - Stopped
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server] 14:17:18.013 INFO -
>   Stopped org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@741a8937
>   14:17:18.039 INFO - Stopped HttpContext[/wd,/wd] 14:17:18.055 INFO -
>   Stopped HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
>   14:17:18.071 INFO - Stopped HttpContext[/,/] 14:17:18.071 INFO -
>   Stopped org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@6c40365c [JsonMessageSender]
>   Sending message [SuiteMessage ==> suite:Default suite, ending,
>   methodCount:5] 14:17:18.073 INFO - Exiting session cleaner thread
>   [BaseMessageSender] Admin message:>ACK [BaseMessageSender] Received
>   ACK:>ACK [BaseMessageSender] Admin message:>ACK [BaseMessageSender]
>   Received ACK:>ACK
>
> ## =============================================== Default suite Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
>
> Creating D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo Selenium
>   Automation\Automation\test-output\junitreports\TEST-tests.testdriver.TpaeTestDriver.xml
>   [TestNG] Time taken by
>   org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@2c34f934: 7 ms Creating
>   D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo Selenium
>   Automation\Automation\test-output\testng-failed.xml Creating
>   D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo Selenium
>   Automation\Automation\test-output\Default suite\testng-failed.xml
>   [BaseMessageSender] Admin message:>STOP [TestNG] Time taken by
>   [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 12 ms Creating
>   D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo Selenium
>   Automation\Automation.\tests\testoutput\tpae\Week_10\2018_03_05__02_15_45PM\testng-results.xml
>   Creating D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo Selenium
>   Automation\Automation\test-output\testng-failed.xml Creating
>   D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo Selenium
>   Automation\Automation\test-output\Default suite\testng-failed.xml
>   [TestNG] Time taken by
>   framework.listeners.report.ReporterListener@5c5eefef: 66 ms Creating
>   D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo Selenium
>   Automation\Automation\test-output\index.html [TestNG] Time taken by
>   org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@45f45fa1: 37 ms Creating
>   D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo Selenium
>   Automation\Automation\test-output\old\Default suite\toc.html Creating
>   D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo Selenium
>   Automation\Automation\test-output\old\Default suite\Default
>   test.properties Creating D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST
>   AUTO\Maximo Selenium Automation\Automation\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\index.html Creating D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST
>   AUTO\Maximo Selenium Automation\Automation\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\main.html Creating D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST
>   AUTO\Maximo Selenium Automation\Automation\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\groups.html Creating D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST
>   AUTO\Maximo Selenium Automation\Automation\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\methods.html Creating D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST
>   AUTO\Maximo Selenium Automation\Automation\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\methods.html Creating D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST
>   AUTO\Maximo Selenium Automation\Automation\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\methods.html Creating D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST
>   AUTO\Maximo Selenium Automation\Automation\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\methods.html Creating D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST
>   AUTO\Maximo Selenium Automation\Automation\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\methods.html Creating D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST
>   AUTO\Maximo Selenium Automation\Automation\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\methods.html Creating D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST
>   AUTO\Maximo Selenium Automation\Automation\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\methods.html Creating D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST
>   AUTO\Maximo Selenium Automation\Automation\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\methods-alphabetical.html Creating
>   D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo Selenium
>   Automation\Automation\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\methods-alphabetical.html Creating
>   D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo Selenium
>   Automation\Automation\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\methods-alphabetical.html Creating
>   D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo Selenium
>   Automation\Automation\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\methods-alphabetical.html Creating
>   D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo Selenium
>   Automation\Automation\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\methods-alphabetical.html Creating
>   D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo Selenium
>   Automation\Automation\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\methods-alphabetical.html Creating
>   D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo Selenium
>   Automation\Automation\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\methods-alphabetical.html Creating
>   D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo Selenium
>   Automation\Automation\test-output\old\Default suite\classes.html
>   Creating D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo Selenium
>   Automation\Automation\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\reporter-output.html Creating
>   D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo Selenium
>   Automation\Automation\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\methods-not-run.html Creating
>   D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo Selenium
>   Automation\Automation\test-output\old\Default suite\testng.xml.html
>   Creating D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo Selenium
>   Automation\Automation\test-output\old\index.html [TestNG] Time taken
>   by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@29f69090: 104 ms [TestNG]
>   Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter@214b199c: 5 ms
>   Creating D:\Profiles\valegoupil\Desktop\TEST AUTO\Maximo Selenium
>   Automation\Automation\test-output\testng-results.xml [TestNG] Time
>   taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@1f1c7bf6: 6 ms

Comment: Your class is calling an unsupported command from the Selenium library. You'll have to dig in the code to find out which one.

Comment: Ok, i think it's the method "GetSize()" ! thx i'll try

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution : 
A method getSize() and getPosition was on an older library (selenium-java-2.xx.x.jar)and is not present in the newest library.